# Does my PCI card have shared interrupts?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, interrupts

I'm trying to get VGA passthrough working on VirtualBox with a Windows guest.  [Per the VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough):

```
Limitations:
1. Only PCI cards with non-shared interrupts (such as using MSI on host) are supported at the moment.
```

How do I determine whether my secondary PCI video card has shared interrupts?  I see nothing obvious in /proc/interrupts... but possibly that's because I already have my secondary card associated with pci-stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the interrupts in use on your system with `lsdev` which is part of the [procinfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=procinfo&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package.

It can be installed with the command `sudo apt-get install procinfo`

Once installed you can issue the command 'lsdev'

You should get output similar to this:

```
$ lsdev
Device            DMA   IRQ  I/O Ports
------------------------------------------------
0000:00:02.0                   f000-f03f
0000:00:1f.2                   f060-f07f   f080-f083   f090-f097   f0a0-f0a3   f0b0-f0b7
0000:00:1f.3                   f040-f05f
0000:02:00.0                     e000-e07f
acpi                      9 
ACPI                           0400-0403   0404-0405   0408-040b   0410-0415   0420-042f   0450-0450
ahci                     41      f060-f07f     f080-f083     f090-f097     f0a0-f0a3     f0b0-f0b7
atl1c                              e000-e07f
cascade             4       
dma                            0080-008f
dma1                           0000-001f
dma2                           00c0-00df
ehci_hcd:usb1            16 
ehci_hcd:usb2            23 
eth0                     45 
fpu                            00f0-00ff
i8042                  1 12 
i915                     43 
it87                             0a35-0a36       0a35-0a36
iTCO_wdt                       0430-0433     0460-047f
keyboard                       0060-0060   0064-0064
mei_me                   42 
PCI                          0000-0cf7 0cf8-0cff 0d00-ffff   e000-efff
pic1                           0020-0021
pic2                           00a0-00a1
pnp                            0200-020f   0454-0457   0458-047f   04d0-04d1   0500-057f   0680-069f   0a00-0a0f   0a20-0a2f   0a30-0a3f   164e-164f   ffff-ffff     ffff-ffff
rtc0                      8    0070-0077
snd_hda_intel            44 
timer                     0 
timer0                         0040-0043
timer1                         0050-0053
vesafb                         03c0-03df
xhci_hcd                 40
```

As you can see the IRQ's in use are listed in the IRQ column. By reviewing this information you can determine whether you have devices sharing an IRQ (interrupt).

Comment: In your example (as on my system), none of the PCI addresses have an interrupt associated with them.  Is that as expected?

Comment: To clarify: would lsdev only show the interrupt after the device is associated with a kernel module?

Comment: These details vary depending on the system. You can check your BIOS and see if there's an option to specifically manually assign an IRQ to your specific PCI card thus insuring that it isn't shared. (Of couorse you'll still have to verify all the points listed in section 9.6 of the doc you referenced and keep in mind support is experimental. Sorry I don't have dual screens for testing.

Comment: I imagine we can determine that by comparing the output of  'lspci -k  with the output of `lsdev`

Comment: Thanks, I see no change in behaviour when the device is or isn't associated with the pci-stub driver.  I'll assume it's not sharing an interrupt for now.